# Faster pivot tables in Excel

Tags: excel, sql

I'm trying to build up a report of data in a SQL database using Excel.  I am able to create connections and pull data into pivot tables and pivot charts.

However, I don't like having to create a new connection for every different query I want to run. Is it possible to have one single datasource connection open to my whole database, and then specify queries for each pivot table?  This could also potentially improve refreshing performance as Excel doesn't have to create a new connection for each query.

Are there perhaps better tools for graphing lots of different SQL queries?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, it is called PowerPivot. You can set up query to be source of a table. And using this table you can build up pivot charts, reports etc. Then by clicking one button or simple macro, you can tell powerpivot to refresh all data